# syntax error in tsquery : parameter with whitespaces

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have this Full-Text-Search function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_questions(psearch text)
  RETURNS TABLE (questionid INTEGER) AS $func$
BEGIN
  return QUERY
  SELECT DISTINCT (questions.publicationid)
  FROM questions
  WHERE to_tsvector(coalesce(questions.title, '')) @@ to_tsquery(psearch)
        OR
        publicationid IN (
          SELECT DISTINCT(publications.publicationid) FROM publications WHERE to_tsvector(coalesce(publications.body, '')) @@ to_tsquery(psearch)
        )
  ;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

but it only works with a single word parameter. If I search for "user test", it returns

`ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery: "user test"`

Is there any way to search for texts with whitespaces in it?

Kind regards

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found how to solve it.
Here it goes

Replace:
`to_tsquery(psearch)`

with:
`plainto_tsquery(psearch)`

Comment: If you are [wondering, why](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html): *`to_tsquery` creates a `tsquery` value from querytext, which must consist of single tokens separated by the tsquery operators & (AND), | (OR), ! (NOT), and <-> (FOLLOWED BY), possibly grouped using parentheses. In other words, **the input to `to_tsquery` must already follow the general rules for tsquery input***

Comment: Note that it will AND all the tokens.

Answer (score 3):

You can put single quotes around your terms and still use `to_tsquery()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use arbitrary operator to join tokens:

```
select to_tsquery('simple', 'نون & خ')

'نون' & 'خ'
```

or:

```
select to_tsquery('simple', 'نون | خ')

'نون' | 'خ'
```