# Error in tsquery containing whitespaces

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have read this post:

[syntax error in tsquery : parameter with whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669338/syntax-error-in-tsquery-parameter-with-whitespaces)

And I still have trouble with whitespaces within my query:

```
        IF search_term <> '' THEN
            $3 := 'plainto_tsquery(''' || $3 || ':*'') @@ textsearchable_index_col';
        ELSE
            $3 := '
```

I get the following mistake:

```
postgres_1       | ERROR:  syntax error in tsquery: "Test Test:*"
```

Please help

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do here. What do you expect your query to be?

Comment: @JacobH i had hoped my query would resolve to : ```'Test' & 'Test'```

Comment: Edit: i had posted the wrong query. Sorry. This is about the ```plainto_tsquery```